# Start PendingIntent for result

Tags: android

I implement `Activity X`. I got a `PendingIntent P` from a `Service S`. I know for sure, that P points to **unknown** `Activity Y` which returns result R via its `setResult` method.

How should I start P in X, in order to receive the result R in `X.onActivityResult`?

Comment: PS. As with the usual `startActivityFotResult` call, I would also like to be notified when Y is cancelled (R equals `RESULT_CANCELED` in this case).

Answer (score 8):

Google Play Services uses `PendingIntent` objects to resolve permission errors in the same scenario:

```
IntentSender intentSender = pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
activity.startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
```

See [Activity.startIntentSenderForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startIntentSenderForResult(android.content.IntentSender,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) for documentation.